# OpenCV imshow set color of pillarbox

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I am using opencv in Python to play a video file full screen. The video is 4:3 aspect ratio, and imshow is by default maintaining the aspect ratio by creating a gray pillarbox along the right side of the screen.

I have not been succesfull in finding any documentation about how to manipulate this – i.e. how to change the color of the pillarbox / what I would presume is the default color of the empty window at the OS level? If changing the color is not explicitly supported by opencv is there a workaround? i.e. draw a black rectangle underneith the video frame?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3  

import cv2 as cv


cap = cv.VideoCapture("video.mp4")

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret,frame = cap.read()

    frame = cv.resize(frame,(720,480))

    cv.imshow("video", frame)

    cv.namedWindow("video", cv.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
    cv.setWindowProperty("video", cv.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN, cv.WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
    

    if cv.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break


cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: try to use cv2.setWindowProperty(window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,
                              cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)  instead of cv2.setWindowProperty(window_name, cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,
                              cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)

Comment: the appearance of any "pillarbox" depends very specifically on the GUI backend. this doesn't look like the win32 backend, so maybe you're on linux or osx. -- use a proper GUI toolkit, or submit a feature request. OpenCV plans to, eventually, replace all the different GUI backends with plain OpenGL (or something like that) for all platforms.

Comment: @lamourette jean-baptiste. It had no effect on Linux. It's nearly identical.I have been testing.